# Points system in Unity not working. I want to count points but make both objects disappear and it's not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, collision

I'm developing a game, but I have hit a breakpoint and I can't figure a solution for my problem.
I want to make a bullet and an object, and when they collide, they both disappear and ads 1 point to a counter. I have tried a few different ways but nothing has worked. I think it's because the bullet disappears after it hits the object.

The bullet script:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Object")
    {
        points = points + 1;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

The points script:

```
void Update()
{
    if (bullet.points == 1)
    {
       pointcounter++;
    }
}
```

I made it `if (bullet.points == 1)` because the bullet will destroy the object after it hits so it will reset to 0 automatically (at least I think it will).

I have also tried doing it in the bullet script and not using a points script but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry for bad english btw.

Comment: your english is good enough. However the supplied information is lacking [mcve] please

Comment: Hello, I'd say the problem is design. You need a centralized class that handles points, so that you won't depend on signals, `if`s or anything that might forget collision or the last point it had; something like a 'Scoreboard` or `ScoreManager` or something similar. In this case, in collision you'd just call `Scoreboard.AddPoints(1)` to add a point. If it's multiplayer, that will complicate the code, but it is doable with a few changes, but same concept. Also, consider using `GameObject.CompareTag()` for tags, instead of `==` as this is the way Unity recommends to evaluate tags.

Comment: @TheNomad, after posting the question I asked a friend and he told me the same thing and now I got my point system working, thank you so much and I will consider using the 'GameObject.CompareTag()' I will maybe test it later today, thank you so much for your help

Comment: No worries. If you have other problems, post a new question. As BugFinder said, you explained it well enough and your English was good :) Good luck with the project !